# java Error: Could not find or load main class test.HelloWorld

Tags: java

java1.8.0_261
F:\DMP\HelloWorld.java

```
package test;

public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Hello World");
}
}
```

F:\DMP>javac HelloWorld.java -d .

F:\DMP>java test.HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class test.HelloWorld

this is the simplest java,but I can not find the reason

Comment: The HelloWorld class should be in a folder called test given your package declaration. Try it with this layout and it will work.

Comment: For the above to work the "HelloWorld.class" file must be in a directory called "test", AND you have to be in the directory >above< "test"

Comment: I've just tried it *exactly* as stated, and can't reproduce the problem. While it's certainly better to put the source files in the appropriate package structure, it's not *required* (so long as you specify all the source files you want to compile explicitly).

Comment: @StephenC: But that's exactly what the OP has done - with `javac HelloWorld.java -d .` a directory called `test` will be created, and they *are* running it still from the same directory (DMP). As I say, I've tried exactly the OP's steps, and they worked fine for me.

Comment: Hmmm.  Then perhaps the OP has set CLASS_PATH to something that is incompatible with the file location.  @Venus add `-cp .` to the `java` command line.  That explicitly tell `java` to only look for stuff in / under the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

As @JonSkeet pointed out, and as I checked myself as well, your code should work fine.

Perhaps it is something wrong with your classpath; as indicated by @StephenC and @g00se in their comments, you can try running your program by explicitly including the current directory as your class path by providing the `-cp` flag:

```sh
F:\DMP>java -cp . test.HelloWorld
```

As an alternative, you can try a different approach and try defining your file structure according to your java package - it's always good practice to do so and it can help you avoid some mistakes.

I mean, if you placed your class in the `test` package:

```java
package test;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

Your folder structure can look like:

```
test/
  HelloWorld.java
```

Equivalently:

```
F:\DMP\test\HelloWorld.java
```

Then, compile your code like this:

```sh
F:\DMP>javac test\HelloWorld.java
```

You should be able to run your program like this:

```sh
F:\DMP>java test.HelloWorld
```

Comment: "The problem is that your file structure has to be according to your java package." No it doesn't. The OP is specifying the Java file to compile *and* specifying `-d`, which means the class files should be automatically created in the right place. I've just tried the steps they've shown, and they worked fine.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, it is an honor. My bad, I totally agree with you, even though I edited the answer later, I misunderstood the use of the `-d` flag here. Thank you very much for pointed me my error.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with any of that but for one invisible thing - the classpath.
`java -cp . test.HelloWorld` should fix the problem.
You need possibly to find out why/how the wrong one was set

Comment: Much better- thanks :)

Comment: So it works now after the `-cp` thing?

Comment: @g00se,yes.   F:\DMP\test>javac -d . HelloWorld.java , F:\DMP\test>java -cp . test.HelloWorld works

Comment: Good. The answer needs to be changed.

Comment: @g00se , I can not edit the answer, it says: Suggested edit queue is full

Comment: @jccampanero thanks but
>You should be able to run your program like this:<
wouldn't work, so needs to be edited. The classpath thng is not a 'consideration' but crucial

Comment: @g00se I agree and disagree with you ;) I think it made sense according to the answer redaction, but I edited the answer again. Please, see the edit.

Comment: @jccampanero OK I'll leave it there but in closing, note that your `javac` command won't run. You need a backslash not a forward slash

Comment: Thank again @g00se. I actually tested the solution, and I use unix, not windows. This is why I used a forward slash.